# "Penser la femme qui écrits": why the s in écrits?

Tags: grammaire

I'm reading the book *Femmes et littérature*, and the title of the first chapter reads "Penser la femme qui écrits". I would have expected that to read "Penser la femme qui écrit", but this seems like an odd place to let slip a typo... am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in your edition; the [present edition](https://flipbook.cantook.net/?d=%2F%2Fwww.edenlivres.fr%2Fflipbook%2Fpublications%2F560386.js&oid=3&c=&m=&l=&r=&f=pdf)  shows that.

Comment: I wanted to post a similar answer; that is, it is a misprint. But I was not, I must admit, 100% sure:-)! [After having pronounced 'cul' for several years as kul I learned today that is ku...I cannot be 100% sure for the French language again:-)! C'est la faute de Voltaire comme le dicton dit !] It is great that you found the link.

Comment: @Dimitris Those little problems are things we all have to live with, more or less, unless we are deeply involved in the language, such as "académiciens". After all, why there exists  the "Académie" and full time people attached to it (the "académiciens") is that it takes someone's entire day's work  every day in order for them to know  really well what is what in matters of language. You'll never be sure in all cases. I was rather sure myself about this case, but still, I didn't despair from finding something I had never seen yet.

Comment: @Dimitris. The phonetic transcription for *cul* should be [ky]. The word *cou* is pronounced [ku].